# Is there a way to determine the destination path of a symlink in node?

Tags: node.js, symlink, fs, symlink-traversal

#### Situation

I just ran into an odd situation that should not happen often, but I would like to prevent it from ever happening again.

I have a chunk of code that creates a deep dive directory list of all the files in a source folder and all of its children folders.

In general this has never been a problem, until today.

I had a fellow dev that accidentally set a symlink of a sub folder to point back at the parent folder. This caused my deep dive to recuse until it crashed.

For example:

```
topfolder
topfolder/sub1 - real folder
topfolder/sub2 - symlink back to topfolder
```

My code read all the files in `topfolder` and then all files in `topfolder/sub1` with no problems. Then, since `topfolder/sub2` points back to `topfolder` I read all the files in `topfolder/sub2`, which are the same as in `topfolder` and then `topfolder/sub2/sub1` and then `topfolder/sub2/sub2` and on to `topfolder/sub2/sub2/sub2`, etc.

#### My question

Is there a way, in node.js to determine the destination of a symlink? I figure if I can create a list of folders I have read and, when running into the symlink above, I determine that the destination is really a folder I have already read then I just skip that folder.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way, in node.js to determine the destination of a symlink?

Yes. [`fs.readlink(dir)`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readlink_path_options_callback) will return the destination of the symlink if it is one, an error otherwise.

```
fs.readlink("sub2", function(err, destination){
  if(err)
    //sub2 is not a symlink, proceed to go into it
  else if(destination)
    //sub2 is a symlink, check if 'destination' is a folder we have already been through
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices (*The Node documentation can be hard to use, so I also supply links to geeksforgeeks.*) :

1. **fs.readLink** on [Node](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesreadlinkpath-options) or [Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-fs-readlink-method/)
2. **fs.readLinkSync** on [Node](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreadlinksyncpath-options) or [Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-fs-readlinksync-method/)

Example with readlink:

```js
fs.readlink(fullPath, (err, linkString) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.log('LINK STRING', linkString);
    }
});
```

With readlinkSync:

```js
const linkString = fs.readlinkSync(fullPath);
debug('LINK STRING', linkString);
```